# Multiple REST endpoints

Tags: services

I have an endpoint, which is active and working for more than a year, and I recently had the need to add a new endpoint, which obviously has a different url ("Path to endpoint").

For both, however, I need to use the login functionality, and other custom actions (each one has its own url, callback and access callback, in two separated custom modules).

But on every call, i can see that both endpoints are being requested, all arguments are being doubled etc. Here's the `$controller` as seen from `hook_services_request_preprocess_alter`:

```
Array
(
    [help] => Array
        (
            [0] => Description from endpoint 1
            [1] => Description from endpoint 2
        )

    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => MY_FIRST_MODULE_callback_function
            [1] => MY_SECOND_MODULE_callback_function
        )

    [access callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => MY_FIRST_MODULE_access_callback_function
            [1] => MY_SECOND_MODULE_access_callback_function
        )

    [args] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => email
                    [type] => string
                    [description] => Email
                    [source] => Array
                        (
                            [data] => email
                        )

                    [optional] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => email
                    [type] => string
                    [description] => Email
                    [source] => Array
                        (
                            [data] => email
                        )

                    [optional] => 1
                )

        )

    [etc] => ....

)
```

This happens whichever url is requested, it's causing both the iOS and Android apps to crash, and i couldn't find a way around it.

What should / can I do to run both endpoint independently, and why are both getting invoked even if the url ("Path to endpoint") is different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a distinct resource name, or simply enable the same resource on the other services endpoint to use it there.

To debug issues with the controller, you can check in [`RESTServer.inc`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!services!servers!rest_server!includes!RESTServer.inc/7) in particular the functions `getController` and `resolveController`. Adding some debug/logging code there may help to resolve the issue.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i'm already using distinct resources names for the custom actions, but i can't rename the /user/ actions... and both endpoints have all required resources enabled.

Comment: @Giona: That's curious, perhaps some odd configuration there. Please see my updated answer with more debug info.

Comment: Thanks @David Thomas, debugging there led me to the actual problem: in the new endpoint, i had both the old and the new resources list enabled, and disabling the old ones fixed the issue. I still don't get why they should be there as the endpoint path is completely different, but whatever, it works now! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Giona, glad to hear it! all the best.